# How can I compute a property based on another element's property?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to show/hide elements based on the availability of camera.

The **detect-camera**, **camera-detached** and **create-welcome** all are inside main **create-app**.

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.html">

<link rel="import" href="detect-camera.html">
<link rel="import" href="camera-detached.html">
<link rel="import" href="create-welcome.html">

<dom-module id="create-app">
  <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>

        <detect-camera found=[[found]]></detect-camera>
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{!allowed}}">
            <camera-detached></camera-detached>
        </template>
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{allowed}}">
            <create-welcome></create-welcome>
        </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    class CreateApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'create-app';
      }

      constructor() {
        super();
      }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          allowed: {
            type: Boolean,
            computed: '_isAllowed(found)'
          }
        };
      }

      _isAllowed(found) {
        return found;
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(CreateApp.is, CreateApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The **camera-detached** and **create-welcome** will be displayed on the logic, if or not the "**found**" property of **detect-camera** is true.

All the logic of detecting the camera is inside **detect-camera**. The code inside **detect-camera** sets its attribute "**found**" property/attribute.

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<dom-module id="detect-camera">
  <template>
  </template>

  <script>
    class DetectCamera extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'detect-camera';
      }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          found: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: false,
            reflectToAttribute: true,
            notify: true
          }
        }
      }

      constructor() {
        super();
        this._foundChanged
      }

      _foundChanged() {
        this.found = true;
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(DetectCamera.is, DetectCamera);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I want to compute the "**allowed**" based on the computed "**found**" property.

Comment: at a glance: you're missing some quotes `found=[[found]]` here. also, not 100% sure, but i think this will not work as you expect it to `if="{{!allowed}}"`.
`this._foundChanged` also an invalid call to a method. One last thing: pretty sure you will need 2-way binding on `found` if you want to be able to use it int the computed `isAllowed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two-way binding:

```
<detect-camera found="{{found}}"></detect-camera>
```

or listen for the `found` property to change:

```
<detect-camera on-found-changed="onFoundChanged"></detect-camera>
```

If you use the event listener approach, you just need to update a local property in your CreateApp element:

```
onFoundChanged(newVal, oldVal) {
  this.hasCamera = newVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could query the Shadow DOM from `create-app`, looking for the `detect-camera` element and check its attributes.

But that wouldn't be very Polymer-ish or extensible for that matter. In general data should flow down by attributes/properties and up by events.

So I would recommend that from the `detect-camera` element, where you set the `found` attribute you would also trigger a custom event, let's say `camera-found` and in this wrapping element you would start assuming that it's not and update it with a listener on that event.

Take a look [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events) at dispatchEvent and hot to listen for it. Don't forget the note about `bubbles: true, composed: true` to be able to listen for the custom event from "outside"

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, Some one over Slack named "fm" found the "something missing" in my code. He just notice that there is a missing quotation and a two way binding in my code.

`<detect-camera found={{allowed}}></detect-camera>` should be `<detect-camera found="{{allowed}}"></detect-camera>`

Also, we don't need to compute the "**allowed**" in "**create-app**" in this case. It's been automatically set by "**found**" property.